# Radial Reingold Tilford Tree remove root node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, nodes

I have been looking for a method to remove the root node from my radial Tilford tree but no luck so far. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220329/d3-js-tree-node-layout-remove-root-node#), but the answer provided is not specific enough to completely understand where I need to use `d.depth > 0`. I have attempted add this line of code in locations that made sense but was not successful (e.g. node.append and .data(nodes)). snippet attached is similar to the location user @JSBob was referring to in the other question, any direction would be helpful as I am new to D3!

```
function createVisualization(root){
  //if (error) throw error;
  drawLegend();
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root), 
      links = tree.links(nodes);
      console.log(nodes);

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
      .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
      .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
      .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc);

  node.append("circle").attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    if(d.size == 0) {
       return "#8c6226"; //Brown
    } else if(d.size == 1){
      return "#DC143C"; //Crimson
    } else if(d.size == 2){
      return "#FFA500"; //Orange
    } else if(d.size == 3){
      return "#32CD32"; //LimeGree
    } else if(d.size == 4){
      return "#1E90FF"; //DodgerBlue
    }
    ;})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.source.depth != 0})
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);
```

to remove the links to the root node and

```
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.depth != 0})
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
```

to remove the root node

See the example : http://plnkr.co/edit/GkXtUoAvUa6nijNCERxz?p=preview

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of the filter function. This was really helpful, Thanks Tim! Follow up question, now that I am displaying all nodes greater than depth = 0, is is possible to recentre my depth = 1 node? I tried adjusting transform values with no luck.

Comment: You want to merge all node with a depth of 1?

Answer (score 0):

What @JSBOB says is that when you make the circle for the root node, set its radius 0 as show below:

```
  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      if (d.depth == 0) {//for root node depth will be 0
        return 0;//make the circle's radius 0 for root node.
      } else {
        return 4.5;
      }
    }).style("fill", function(d) { ... });
```

working sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MebfWS0u6ITa1PG5NklT?p=preview)

Comment: You should add `if(d.depth ==0){return ""} else return d.name;` to remove the title too

Comment: Yep i agree..But @Tim in the code snippet provided by OP above there is no text part so i didn't mention it.